# Is it possible to serialize the instance of the SqlDataSource into structured text, such as XML?

Tags: asp.net, xml, sqldatasource

I'm developing an in-house ASP.Net application, due to some reason, I've to create dynamic page with dynamic created SqlDataSource(s). So, I'm finding a way to serialize and persist the SqlDataSource instance(s) to structured text(s) (e.g. XML), and later on de-serialize back from the structured text(s), then instantiate the corresponding object(s) of SqlDataSource.

Please kindly advise the simplest way to do that.

Thank you!

William

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way will be to serialize relevant properties (such as Connection String, SelectCommand) - these are any way strings. For de-serializing, just create a new `SqlDataSource` and set these properties (or pass them via constructor).

Comment: Can I iterate over the list of properties? I don't want to do the serialization manually, that it may miss up something.

Comment: @William, you can use reflection to enumerate properties of any object. You may also use `DefaultValue` attribute on a property to decide if the value has been changed or not. However said that, I will still recommend to use manual mode because its efficient.